# VMWare networking problems

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, ping

I have WS 2008 installed as a guest under VMWare workstation 6.5. Networking is set to bridged and all firewalls are off. I am seeing some very weird problems with the network (mainly evidenced through ping).

Here is the network setup:

Host pc "Boris" 192.168.0.2 (static ip)

Guest (virtual) pc "Boris-ws2008" 192.168.0.72 (dynamic ip assigned by router)

Both pc's have their gateway set to 192.168.0.1 (NetGear router) and everything is on the same subnet.
The router lists both "Boris" and "Boris-ws2008" correctly in the routing table, and all pc's concerned can ping the router and access the internet with no trouble.

The problem:

From the guest "Boris-ws2008" I cannot ping the host pc "Boris" either by name or ip, getting the following error:

Pinging 192.168.0.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.72: Destination host unreachable.

From the host "Boris" I can ping "Boris-ws2008" by ip, but not by name, getting the following error:

Ping request could not find host boris-ws2008.

The Really Weird Bit:
The strange thing is that from another computer on the network I can successfully ping and Remote Desktop with no bother to "Boris-ws2008" WTF!?

Any ideas?

Comment: I should also add that I have another VM added to Boris called "Boris-xp" which shows *exactly* the same problems/symptoms as "Boris-ws2008". All the VMs are freshly installed...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the cause is, but I'd be looking at your routing table and arp cache on boris and boris-ws2008 as a starting point for finding out. Also host firewalls, if any.

Comment: hi - not sure what an arp cache is - can you please explain?

Comment: arp cache is where the mapping of IP to mac addresses is stored.
Some times it gets corrupted.
I think the windows cmd line command for it is `arp -a` to see it. Not sure to clear it (I'm a linux guy).

Answer (score 1):

You have a fairly simple setup - your symptoms suggest to me a subnet mask issue, although you say it is correct. Could you check again that the subnet masks are set correctly on the guests? Pasting in your question the output of "ipconfig" from both host and guest would help too.

Update: From the info below, try bouncing your router to reset its arp cache.

Comment: ipconfigs and routing table added.

Answer (score 0):

Host IPConfig:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Boris
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : NETGEAR WN121T Wireless USB 2.0 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-18-4D-75-F7-9C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9fb:4e77:31e0:b423%12(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301996109
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-11-8E-41-23-00-16-E6-5E-06-91
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-16-E6-5E-06-91
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::95b7:68e0:f701:e2cd%14(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.179.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 385896534
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-11-8E-41-23-00-16-E6-5E-06-91
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e93a:8370:7dc5:bdf2%16(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.198.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 419450966
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-11-8E-41-23-00-16-E6-5E-06-91
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5F7BF77F-C25E-477A-A451-7D0965D7CFD7}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E197B45C-7D40-4F8D-BF44-EAF49EB98DF0}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{76D50431-6B22-4DCE-9817-44BFC5C89719}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A0723E40-25A0-4F94-BAB0-A3B4E26FBC10}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes



Guest IPConfig:

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : BORIS-WS2008
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-07-7B-FA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.72(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, May 30, 2009 8:38:05 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, June 02, 2009 8:38:06 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{4F1E912C-16C1-4D02-953E-8B1F9FDEBCBE}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes


ROUTING TABLE FROM ROUTER (192.168.0.1)
#  IP Address  Device Name  MAC Address 
1 192.168.0.2 BORIS 00:18:4D:75:F7:9C 
2 192.168.0.64 DOUGGIE 00:1F:3B:3B:83:BF
3 192.168.0.72 BORIS-WS2008 00:18:4D:75:F7:9C
```

Comment: Not sure why, but the router sees the same MAC address for both the host and guest VM:  (00:18:4D:75:F7:9C0

1 192.168.0.2 BORIS 00:18:4D:75:F7:9C 
3 192.168.0.72 BORIS-WS2008 00:18:4D:75:F7:9C

Comment: Has the guest config changed from NATted to Bridged?  The guest VM may need to be restarted, or possibly the host, or ARP table cleared in the router.

Comment: Mike is correct, I don't think the MAC address should be the same there. Try bouncing your router.

Comment: I've rebooted the router and the host as well - still no change.
I don't understand the problem with the MAC address - surely the host and guest *should* have the same MAC address as they are sharing the same network card (Bridged)?